# Power BI visualizations: axis names are displayed as "sum of xyz" instead of "xyz"

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I'm pretty new to Power BI.

I've been adding columns to different charts, graphs and tables and everytime, the axis names/column names have a "Sum of" infront of them even though the values being used in the graph are not discrete values.

[image: pbi ss]

How do I fix this to show only the column names as axis names?

PS, I'm following these videos to learn: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NV5Jtbhfcw&list=PLUaB-1hjhk8HqnmK0gQhfmIdCbxwoAoys&index=8&ab_channel=AlexTheAnalyst

I tried to check if any columns have a "don't summarize" type option when I right click them but they're not present.

Comment: Don't drop fields into the visuals directly. Create measures, name them as needed, and use them instead. Once created, the same measure can be used in many places.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the label. Select your chart, go to X/Y-axis double click. Type what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Is there any way to edit the default behavior though? It will be tedious to rename everything once there are many elements involved